# Create Schema Clones with RedGate sqlcompare & table of server names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, redgate

Ok, so I have taken an old batch file that previous DBA's have used to "clone" the schema from Production databases on multiple servers and drop them in one network directory.  This batch file was updated manually so I am trying to automate it.  We have a support dbase with a table that has all of the server names in it so I was figuring easiest would be a cursor (I know, but for this not an issue) to while through the list of server names executing the "sqlcompare" command line stuff for each.  Apparently though it makes a new command line line for every individual database on each server so my variable is returning more than one result.  There HAS to be a better way to do this, I feel like I must be going about this all wrong, any help is appreciated:

```
  DECLARE @RowCount INT = 1
 ,@index INT = 1
 ,@outputfolder varchar(100)
 ,@servername varchar(100)
 ,@environment varchar(50)
 ,@OutputPath  varchar(100)
 ,@sqlcmd nvarchar (100)

SET @outputfolder = GETDATE()
SET @OutputPath = '\\<network location to store output files>\'

-- set @outputfolder = '2014.03.10_0900'
SET @servername = '<servername stored in table>'
SET @environment = '<environment variable in table>'
SET @sqlcmd = ':connect '+@servername

DECLARE @redgatecmd varchar(255)
SET @redgatecmd = ''

--SELECT '::'+@environment
SET @redgatecmd = (SELECT DISTINCT 'sqlcompare /s1:'+@servername+' /db1:'+'name'+' /mkscr:"'+@OutputPath+@outputfolder+'\'+@environment+'\'+'name'+'" /options:iw,iu,isn,ie,ic,iup,iweo,infr,idc,idsn,isoa,isb"' from sysdatabases where name not in ( 'tempdb'))
PRINT @redgatecmd

--EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @redgatecmd
```

Comment: Why don't you just schedule the batch file using Task Scheduler?

Comment: Because then I would still have to edit it by hand if any server names change etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something very similar using PowerShell.  And connecting from there to the DB to pull the details.  Tweaked it for your example (though the output directory isn't quite the same and it doesn't have the compare options set)

It was based on this [great article from DataOrge](http://www.dataogre.com/2013/02/12/powershell-just-bring-it-tsql2sday/)

```
#Create your SQL connection string, and then a connection
$ServerAConnectionString = "Data Source=hostname\instance;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=SSPI" # Or instead of integrated auth ;User Id=XXX;PWD=XXX"
$ServerAConnection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ServerAConnectionString);

#Create a Dataset to hold the DataTable 
$dataSet = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "ServerList"
$query = "SET NOCOUNT ON;"
$query = $query + "SELECT name, environment, db "
$query = $query + "FROM   dbo.Servers; "


#Create a DataAdapter which you'll use to populate the DataSet with the results
$dataAdapter = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($query, $ServerAConnection)
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

#Close the connection as soon as you are done with it
$ServerAConnection.Close()


$dataTable = new-object "System.Data.DataTable" "Servers"
$dataTable = $dataSet.Tables[0]


#For every object
$dataTable | FOREACH-OBJECT {
  "Name:  $($_.name)"
  "Database:  $($_.db)"
  "Environment:  $($_.environment)"

  $cmd = "sqlcompare.exe /s1:$($_.name) /db1:$($_.db) /mkscr:$($_.environment+"_"+$_.db)"
  write-host $cmd
  Invoke-Expression $cmd
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is having an issue finding the sqlcompare.exe, do you do something to change dir before that perhaps?

Comment: You can put the full path in (it's in Program Files x86/Red Gate/SQL Compare).  Or add that folder to the PATH.

Comment: I've written an expansion to this script in an article about [Automating Database Deployments](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2014/05/07/automating-deployments-with-the-sql-compare-command-line/)